# Online development VS local development

Tags: odoo

I'm working on my first project in Odoo. If I understand correctly there are 2 ways to develop a project in Odoo: local development and online development.

I have an existing database but I'm wondering if it's best to develop the website locally or online. Or is this a totally different approach?

Is there an advantage to develop locally?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Odoo but normally programmers works on local because of easy to debug. Also if you are works online you have to change server files of all time, its waste of time especially huge projects.

Advantage of online is accessible of everywhere and also there is no hardware limitation.